# How to describe this sentence correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction

Mr. A assigned Mr.B(the factory worker) to operate the xxx machine in accordance with the processing program-related ***documents which consisted of***:

1. design drawings;
2. a checklist of the processing procedure;

In this case, I'm asking whether "*consisted of*" above can used to refer "*as follows*" or should I use the latter for the sake of simplicity?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your question is about the usage of "consist of" or "consisted of" in the sentence, then I would say "consisted of" is the right choice there because "Mr.A assigned Mr.B" which is in past tense.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking whether I can use "consisted of" in this case to refer the meaning "as follows"? Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: consisted of A & B; as follows 1)A 2)B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you want to use past tense (consisted) here.

I would use:

> Mr. A assigned Mr.B (the factory worker) to operate the xxx machine in accordance with the processing program-related documents, **which consist of**...
>
> Mr. A assigned Mr.B (the factory worker) to operate the xxx machine in accordance with the **following** processing program-related documents.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence sounds a little strange overall, but to answer your question,

> ***which consisted of***

could be replaced with:

> ***as follows***

---

An alternative way I would phrase the paragraph is:

> Mr. A assigned Mr. B (the factory worker) the task of operating the xxx machine in accordance with the processing programs' related documents, which consisted of...

...although it still seems like a [run-on sentence](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/runons.htm).  Another option, breaking it up into smaller sentences for the sake of clarity and easy reading:

> Mr. A assigned Mr. B to the xxx machine.  Mr. A then instructed the worker how to operate the machine in accordance with the related Processing Program documents as follows...